# In Meteor, how to remove items from a non-Mongo Collection?

Tags: meteor

In Meteor, I am publishing a collection from a non-Mongo source (IMAP specifically).

```
Meteor.publish("search_results", function(user, password, str) {
  var self = this;
  res_msg = [];

  Imap.connect({...  });

  Imap.search(str, resultcb);
  for (var i = 0; i < res_msg.length; i++) {
    self.set("s_results", Meteor.uuid(), {uid: res_msg[i].uid, date: res_msg[i].date,  headers:res_msg[i].headers});
  }

  self.flush();
  self.complete();
  self.flush();
  console.log("total messages : ", res_msg.length);
});
```

This works fine. However, on the second pass though, new items are appended to the collection. There does not appear to be a way to remove records from a non-Mongo collection.

It seems from the documentation that if I use this.unset, it will change attributes, not remove the record(s).

I can't use collection.remove({}) either client or server side.

Comment: Imap is a Meteor package I wrote that wraps around the [node.js IMAP package](https://github.com/mscdex/node-imap) and puts it into a fiber so it plays nice with Meteor.

Answer (score 1):

I found a really ugly way to do this, so I'm leaving the question open in the hopes that there is a better alternative.

Basically, if you unset all the attributes, the document goes away. The question is how to iterate over the collection within the publish method to find all documents so attributes can be unset. Creating a collection doesn't seem to work, let alone .find();

I stored the list of ids in a separate array. Ugly, I know. I hope you can do better.

```
for (i = 0; i < uuids.length; i++) {
  self.unset("s_results", uuids[i], {});
}
uuids = [];
Imap.search(str, resultcb);
for (var i = 0; i < res_msg.length; i++) {
  var u = Meteor.uuid();
  self.set("s_results", u, {uid: res_msg[i].uid, date: res_msg[i].date, headers:res_msg[i].headers});
  uuids.push(u);
}
```

Comment: I don't think you're far off the mark.  To publish a non-realtime data source, you need some kind of cache so that you can compute the difference between successive queries.

Your `uuids` array is pretty much the same as the internal state kept in the Mongo driver and the merge box.